# In what file is a my struct defined in?

Tags: c

I am working with a standard library with many files. I would like to know where an often-used  typedef struct is defined. I have its name, but that's it.

Is there a way to "programmatically" tell where a given `struct` is defined among a lot of files?

Comment: Ehmmm, use your IDE or grep it?

Comment: I like [ack](http://betterthangrep.com).  `ack 'struct whatever'` should find it for you.

Comment: Windows Search should find it just fine, too.

Comment: if your IDE supports it, `ctags` is also great.

Comment: When you say ""programmatically", do you mean at runtime?

Comment: In "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers", click on it and press F3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't list an OS or an IDE but in Linux I have always used `grep`. I have yet to find an IDE that is good at tracking down typedefs especially since some are wrapped in macros.